# Python *args square using list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function

I am given this question to understand use of functions and passing different variables and types.
It tells us to make a list and task its square using functions.

```
listA=[]
n = int(input("Enter number of elements in the list : "))
def list(n):
    print("\nEnter the elements of your list: ")
    for i in range(n):
        i=input()
        listA.append(i)
list(n)
print("\nThe entered list is: \n",listA)
def square(*args):
    for i in range(len(args)):
         args[i]*=2
square(listA)
```

Comment: Not a solution, but a stunningly bad idea to call a function 'list' - although your code will work, it is a really bad habit to get into.

Comment: Oh okay, will do that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick and easy solution using list comprehensions:

```py
number = int(input('Enter a number: '))
print([i ** 2 for i in range(1, number + 1)])
```

so what this does:

I hope You understand the input and print part.

About the list comprehension:

basically it will append to the list (itself) i raised to the power of 2 and it will do so for every i in the range so for 1, for 2, for 3 and so on

In other words:

The list will append to itself 1 raised to the power of 2, then 2 raised to the power of 2, then 3 raised to the power of 2 until the range is reached (for example 5 so it will continue adding to the list squares until i is 5 and that will be the end of range)

Does this satisfy the requirement:

```py
n = int(input('How many number You want squared?: '))


def given(amount_of_numbers):
    temp = []
    for i in range(1, amount_of_numbers + 1):
        temp.append(i)
    return temp


def square(list_):
    return [i ** 2 for i in list_]


print(square(given(n)))
```

Comment: It doesn't satisfy the requirement to write functions which use variable arguments though. It is clearl that the tutor is just trying to create busy work.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 I guess I missed that part but does it now?

Comment: Both of your functions use a fixed number of arguments. Also since the `square` function changes the list_ in place it is not normal to also return it.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 ok, I got that basically my answer does not help in this case, but why isn't it normal to also return that particular list? and what should I do instead?

Comment: @Matiss - if you look at the standard library (for example) functions/methods which modify an object in place it doesn't return the same object (for example `list.sort()` and `list.append()` both return None. It seems to be a convention - either modify in place or return a new object. If you have a good reason for your functions to do both, then great.,

Answer (score 0):

Your square function wont work at all, if you pass a list to it (as you are doing), then args will be a tuple : (listA, ) - ie a single element tuple where args[0] is the list you have passed. You then loop through the tuple based on it's length - and try to change that tuple.

The problem is the first element you hit is your list, and you then try to do the equivalent of listA*2 - so that duplicates listA and stores that back into the tuple (oops) - I wouldn't be surpised if your code fails.

Also when you call

```
square(listA)
```

You are passing a single argument to the square function - that argument happens to be a list of integers, but it is a single thing.

What you therefore need to to do is convert the list of number into a series of numbers - and you can do that using the * operator as follows :

```
square(*listA)
```

The * operator here unpacks the list into its individual items.

The problem with doing that is that since now that the function is getting multiple integers, the changes you make inside the function to args) wont now change listA.

Note though - the problem statement says to use values between 1 and a limit given by the users: not that you should use arbitrary values given by the user - so although your solutuon will 'work' it doesn't actually do what has been asked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this question requires variable arguments, but take away the unpacking (*) in your function for square, and it will eliminate the runtime error. There are also other things in the code that aren't right. The first is that you need to append the int(i) in your list function (that name needs to be changed), and secondly, the *= does not square the value. See my code for the updated suggestions.

```
listA = []
n = int(input("Enter number of elements in the list : "))


def _list(n):
    print("\nEnter the elements of your list: ")
    for i in range(n):
        i = input()
        listA.append(int(i))


_list(n)
print("\nThe entered list is: \n", listA)


def square(args):
    for i in range(len(args)):
        args[i] = args[i]*args[i]


square(listA)
print('The squared list is: \n', listA)
```

Example:

```
Enter number of elements in the list : 4

Enter the elements of your list: 
3
6
1
6

The entered list is: 
 [3, 6, 1, 6]
The squared list is: 
 [9, 36, 1, 36]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input("Enter number of elements in the list : "))
listA = list(range(1, n + 1))
print("\nThe entered list is: \n", listA)
def square(args):
    for i in range(len(args)): args[i]**=2
square(listA)
print(listA)
```